# Which SVG toolkit would you recommend to use in Java?

Tags: java, svg

As a follow-up to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162991/selecting-proper-toolkit-for-a-2d-simulation-project-in-java), I was wondering what would be the best way to use SVG in a Java project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apache [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) project is an open source SVG renderer written in Java. You can pass it an SVG file, or create a document programatically via a DOM-style API accesssible from Java code.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Batik there is also [SVG Salamander](https://svgsalamander.java.net/).

Personally I prever Salamander, it only doesn't support all SVG features, eg. Gaussian blurring.

Comment: Because Salamander is light-weight. The size of Batik is huge.